# NServiceBus basic message publisher without ravenDB

Tags: c#, nservicebus

Im trying to create a really basic NServicebus.Host application which sends a message every second. I dont want to use any of the NServiceBus persistance stuff which uses RavenDB (ie timeouts/sagas).

Ive done the following:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .DisableTimeoutManager();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MessageSender : IWantToRunWhenTheBusStarts
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public MessageSender(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _bus.Publish(new MyMessage { Timestamp = DateTime.Now });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

however I get an exception on the publish line:

> System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
>   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1
>   getResponse)
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString()
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson()
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectGet(String serverUrl, String key)
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Get>b__0(String
>   u)
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result)
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String
>   method, Func`2 operation)
>          at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Get(String key)
>          at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Load[T](String id)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.d_*81`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Publish[T](T[] messages)
>          at ClassLibrary1.MessageSender.b*_1() in 
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()   InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>          HResult=-2147467259
>          Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
>          Source=System
>          ErrorCode=10061
>          NativeErrorCode=10061
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>               at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
>               at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)

This suggests to me that NServiceBus is still trying to connect to RavenDB.

What else do I need to disable to make this example work?

Why is it even trying to connect to RavenDB for a basic publish?

Note: I have no subscribers yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like NServiceBus also uses RavenDB for subscription storage by default. By specifying an alternate storage mechanism I was able to get this example working.

```
            .MsmqTransport()
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .DisableTimeoutManager();
```

and in the app.config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
        <section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    </configSections>
    <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
    <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="YourQueue" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: FYI when you go to production you'll have to loop in the new separate NH assemblies(this is where the NH sub storage lives).

Comment: Hi Luke, do you have any idea, I am getting this error while NServiceBus Windows Service is started- 

It appears it is looking for RavenDB but we don't have any RavenDB but SQL Server with MSMQ.

MESSAGE:Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:8080